# Python Urllib form help

Tags: python, forms, email, urllib

I am trying to make a program that will access http://mailfreeonline.com/free_anonymous_mail and send me an email. This is what I have so far, it says there is a syntax error with the second colon?

```
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode(
    {'tomailget': 'myemail@gmail.com',
     'fromnameget': 'Matt'
     'frommailget': 'test@test.com'
     'subjectget': 'Subject'
     'messageget': 'Message'     })
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.mailfreeonline.com/free_anonymous_mail", params)
```

Comment: "it says there is a syntax error with the second colon".  Maybe you could include the error message/traceback?

Comment: to format code, just indent it 4 spaces. You can select what you want to indent and press the `{}` button above the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add comma after each parameter, you forgot to do that

```
      params = urllib.urlencode( {'tomailget': 'myemail@gmail.com', 
                                  'fromnameget': 'Matt',    
                                  'frommailget': 'test@test.com', 
                                  'subjectget': 'Subject', 
                                  'messageget': 'Message' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see commas between the elements in the dictionary

```
 {'tomailget': 'myemail@gmail.com',
 'fromnameget': 'Matt'**,**
 'frommailget': 'test@test.com'**,**
 'subjectget': 'Subject'**,**
 'messageget': 'Message'     })
```